# Linq-to-SQL adds unwanted child rows

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using Linq-to-SQL with MVC 3.0. I have a master table associated to a values table through a foreign key (foreign key is the valus table id stored in the master table).

When the values table `id` in the master is changed Linq-to-SQL creates a new (unwanted) row in the values table with all of the columns identical to the selected values row but with a new auto id.

Tracing the code and monitoring the SQL Server table's rows reveals that the the new row is generated from the repository at `db.SubmitChanges();` but tracing through `designer.cs` it's not evident how the unwanted row is added.

Comment: If you add a primary key to the child table it won't happen

Comment: Thanks for your input. The child table contains a primary key. Similar table relations are not expieriencing this. I wonder if it would be a good idea to remove and readd the offending table in the dbml

Comment: having same problem i have many to many table after 3 days i found how to insert records (trough REST/JSON ) to it and now its adds unwanted rows . all this linqtosql ****** with entitiyref and entitiyset ruins everything !!!!